# How do I install dwm on ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

I would like to know how I can easily install dwm window manager on Ubuntu. It would not matter if you only know how to install awesome window manager as they are alike and I like them both. It does not matter if you know through a ppa or how to install through terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It should be pretty straight forward:

```
sudo apt-get install dwm
```

Then just logoff, and at the welcome screen choose `dwm` as your window manager.